# Cannot Sync columns to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I use the Azure SQL DataSync to synchronise some tables from my Database from my Server to Azure. Because I have a new project, I have to sync new tables and columns to Azure.

So I want to add them in my SyncGroup. This works. But when I start the synchronisation I get a `SQL Error Number: 207 Message: Ivalid Column Name 'BeNr'`

In this table a foreign key name is `BeNr`, the primary key of the associated table is also named `BeNr`. But this souldn't be a problem.

But I have a other table which also have a `BeNr`. Can I don't have the same column name in different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of searching. I found the solution.

I already synchronised the table with two columns. Then I add a third one and start the sync. Then the Error came up.

The solution for this:

1. Remove the table from the SyncGroup
2. Start the sync
3. Remove the table from the destination Database
4. Add the table again with all columns (old and new)
5. Sync again

Then it worked in my case.

Comment: please accept and mark it as the answer, This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonYue Yes, I will do it. But I cannot do it until tomorrow. When I want to do it, the information pop ups: "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"